# Service when activity destroy call again onStart

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I have a android Service, in the onStart method i get many Strings from the Intent activity, and then execute a AsynTask to download files from internet.

When the activity is running this works ok, but when i stop the activity, this relaunch the onStart method, but obiusly the intent is null causing me nullPointerException.

What can i do the service dont entry on onStart, and continues the first asyntask to download all the files?

This is my code

```
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        desde = intent.getIntExtra("desde", 0);
        hasta = intent.getIntExtra("hasta", 1);
        email = intent.getStringExtra("email");
        password = intent.getStringExtra("password");

        new DescargaFotos().execute();

    }

@Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        return null;
    }
```

and in Inicio.java (The UI activity)

```
Intent iService = new Intent(contexto,


    ServiceDownloader.class);
                            iService.putExtra("desde", 0);
                            iService.putExtra("hasta", 5);
                            iService.putExtra("email", email);
                            iService.putExtra("password", password);
                            startService(iService);
```

**EDIT:**

New question:

I am using IntentService and i bind the service like this:

```
Intent iService = new Intent(contexto,
                                ServiceDownloader.class);

                        ServiceConnection serviceConector = new ServiceConnection() {

                            @Override
                            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
                                Log.i("INFO", "Service bound ");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name,
                                    IBinder service) {
                                Log.i("INFO", "Service Unbound ");
                            }
                        };

                        iService.putExtra("desde", 0);
                        iService.putExtra("hasta", 50);
                        iService.putExtra("email", email);
                        iService.putExtra("password", password);
                        startService(iService);
                        bindService(iService, serviceConector,
                                Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

And now my problem is, in my galaxy nexus, if i enter in app runtime list, and destroy my app, the service stopped, and stop donwload, stop send notification etc? How must i bind the service to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an IntentService. IntentService is specifically designed to do what you want. You don't have to implement onStart, onStartCommand, etc. The work runs on a background thread. Once the work finishes, the Thread is destroyed.

IntentService will continue to run regardless of the state of the Activity.

One problem you may have is that you're sending out your Intent in the wrong place in your Activity, or you're not checking to see if the operation is complete. Before you send the Intent, check a flag in SharedPreferences (if the flag doesn't exist, it means you're starting for the first time). When you send the Intent, store a flag in SharedPreferences to indicate that you sent it. When your IntentService receives the Intent, have it update the flag to say it received it. Before the IntentService finishes, have it update the flag again. And so forth.

Comment: I use IntentService, and solved my problem, but now there are other, i modify my question.

Comment: @colymore perhaps you should accept it and create a new question in a new question, not modifying this one.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have reputation to comment your question, so I will write a answer :)

First off all, in my opinion, if your Service do just this, get some string and download files from the Internet, you do not need the service. The AsyncTaks is enough to solve your problem and it is more simple to implement. Doing that, you avoid the problem with your intent.

[From Android API:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

> AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.

However, if you decide to continue using a service, lt me know exactly when startService is called in your activity.

If you have some doubt about when use AsyncTask, Service, IntentService and Thread, this **[link](http://madhusudhanrc.blogspot.com.br/2012/05/difference-between-android.html)** can help you.

Comment: I cant use onlye Asyntask because if the user cancel the activity o exits, i want to download all the files, and can be about 30000 jpgs..

Comment: Ok. I understood. So, when/where exactly the you call the startService   method? I think if you update your question with that information more people could help you.

Answer (score 0):

This would be my suggestion...

Use a thread in the service rather then AsyncTask since AsynTask should only be used small task. Check following statement from [AsyncTask javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

> AsyncTask is designed to be a helper class around [Thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html) and [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)
>   and does not  constitute a generic threading framework. AsyncTasks
>   should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the
>   most.) If you need to keep threads running for long periods of time,
>   it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by the
>   java.util.concurrent pacakge such as [Executor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html), [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) and
>   [FutureTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html).

So from your on start check the status of your thread, if it is running then don't do anything, if it is not running then start the thread that would download your images...